# Conditionally hide div on all posts but not category page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How do I hide a div on all posts except posts on category pages in WordPress?

I currently have the following jQuery but can't get it to work -

```
jQuery(function(){
      if (window.location.pathname == "offonalim.com/category/fashion.html"||window.location.pathname == "offonalim.com/category/interior.html"||window.location.pathname == "offonalim.com/category/travel.html"||window.location.pathname == "offonalim.com/category/work.html") {
            jQuery('.qodef-post-title').show();
            jQuery('.qodef-post-info').show();
      } else {
            jQuery('.qodef-post-title').hide();
            jQuery('.qodef-post-info').hide();
      }
 });
```

Comment: **can't get it to work** - explain it in detail. What issue you are facing etc

Comment: In addition to the javascript options, on the php side of things, Wordpress has a function called [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) that may be worth looking into. It's pretty helpful when building templates.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that category pages of your website contains the keyword `"Category"` in each url,
so you can use this keyword to check if the url is having this particular keyword then show or hide divs accordingly

No need to specify full urls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
   val path=window.location.pathname;
      if(window.location.href.indexOf("category") > -1) {
            $('.qodef-post-title').show();
            $('.qodef-post-info').show();
      } else {
            $('.qodef-post-title').hide();
        $('.qodef-post-info').hide();
      }
 }
 myFunction();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) yields the pathname, not the entire URL. So, your code is logically incorrect.

And instead of checking for each path individually, an ideal practice would be to create an array of possible paths and check the location's path in that array. Something like this should work fine:

```
var catPaths = [
  "/category/fashion.html",
  "/category/interior.html",
  "/category/travel.html",
  "/category/work.html"
];

jQuery(function() {
  if (catPaths.includes(window.location.pathname)) {
    jQuery('.qodef-post-title').show();
    jQuery('.qodef-post-info').show();
  } else {
    jQuery('.qodef-post-title').hide();
    jQuery('.qodef-post-info').hide();
  }
});
```

You can further minimize the code by using [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and grouping the selectors:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var includes = catPaths.includes(window.location.pathname);
  jQuery('.qodef-post-title, .qodef-post-info').toggle(includes);
});
```